# click on <i> tag in robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

I am trying to click on the  tag present in the html through robot framework using id attribute.

I have tried:

```
Page Should Contain Element    id=can_edit_132
Click Element    id=can_edit_132
```

Error I am getting:

```
ValueError: ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

Here is my HTML

```
<i ng-if="canEdit() &amp;&amp; isEnabled(Scr)" ng-click="disableScr(scr)"
title="Enabled - Click to disable" class="cursor-pointer fa fa-check-square-o 
fa-lg m-t-sm ng-scope" 
id="can_edit_132"></i>
```

Comment: Are you waiting for the page to finish loading before trying to click the element?

Comment: @BryanOakley i wasn't waiting for the page to load. Hence i was getting that error. I added Set Selenium Speed for delay and it worked as expected

Answer (score 0):

Hi actually i used **Capture Page Screenshot** and saw that the page was still loading so i used **Set Selenium Speed** for delay then it worked.